# Cant find why Im having undefined offset notice

Tags: php

I have this code below in a news-create.php file where I have a form to insert data in my news table.

And all is working fine, unless my images multiple upload, when I insert my news.

Im getting this errors:

**Notice:** Undefined offset: 3 in `$ext = substr($gb['name'][$i],-3);`

**Notice:** Undefined offset: 3 in `if(in_array($gb['type'][$i],$extPerm))`

Can you give some help trying to understand this notices??

**This is what I have:**

Before this code below, Im storing in $f array what User writes in my insert news form and upload my single image of my news and then I do my insert:

```
    $insNews = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO news (img, title, category, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $insNews->bindParam(1,$f['img']);
    $insNews->bindParam(2,$f['title']);
    $insNews->bindParam(3,$f['category']);
    $insNews->bindParam(4,$f['content']);               
    $insNews->execute();
    $insNews = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Im getting my lastInsertId because I also want to create a image gallery to my current news, so I need to associate the news Im current inserting with my gallery table, so I think about this solution, I think it should work...

And then If my insert returns sucess I will do my multiple upload, and insert my gallery of current id in my table gallery:

```
if($insNews->rowCount() >=1){
    if($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']){
        $count = count($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']);
        $gb = $_FILES['gb'];
        $folder = '../galery/';
        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');

        if(!file_exists($folder.$year)){
        mkdir($folder.$year,0755);
        }

        if(!file_exists($folder.$year.'/'.$month)){
        mkdir($folder.$year.'/'.$month,0755);
        }

        for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){

            $ext = substr($gb['name'][$i],-3);
            $name = $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$idlast.'-'.$i.time().'.'.$ext;
            $extPerm = array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
            if(in_array($gb['type'][$i],$extPerm)){
            uploadImage($gb['tmp_name'][$i], $name, '800', $folder);

            //and then I will do my insert into galery table here
            $insGal = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO gallery (img, id_news) VALUES (?, ?)");
            $insGal->bindParam(1,$name);
            $insGal->bindParam(2,$idlast);

            }
        }

    }

    if($f['status'] == '1'){
        echo 'Sucess inserting news';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Sucess intersing news, but you need to active it.';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$i <= $count` to `$i < $count`. When an array contains 3 elements, the indexes run from `0` to `2`. You're going one element too far.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Barmar's answer. It looks to me like you're counting the wrong array for your loop. Your Code:

```
$count = count($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']);//shouldn't this be just $_FILES['gb'] as that's what you're iterating over? 
$gb = $_FILES['gb'];  

//
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ //$count contains the length of $_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think Im also doing correct, Im using my if if($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']) to verify if exists $_FILES['gb'] with index tmp_name, if exists, then I use my variable $count  because I need to know how many images are being sent, so I count how many tmp_names exist, how many images were sending in my form!